# how to solve this module not found error ? pynotifier

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook

I can't seem to install this library for some reason .when I tried installing this lib  First I got a visual studio 14.0 or greater error. I downloaded VS and now im getting  this error .

```
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

This is the error code I faced in the jupyet notebook .

```
  ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-68a18bebc69f> in <module>
          6 import csv
          7 from datetime import datetime,date,timedelta
    ----> 8 from pynotifier import Notification
          9 import warnings
         10 warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
    
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynotifier'
```

I looked up soo many links. none of them seem to work . how to solve this ?

Comment: Have you installed pynotifier? `pip install py-notifier`

Comment: thanks a lot Adid, That did it. I was trying pip install pynotifer suggested in one link. I'm surprised I didn't find this simple solution anywhere else.

Comment: It can be confusing regarding what to install vs what to import - if you search the package up on PyPi it'll tell you exactly what to do for each